# jQuery 1.10.2 events not firing on flash object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, events

HTML

```
<div id="div" tabindex="1">Div</div>
<object id="swf" tabindex="1"><!--Embedded with swfobject--></object>
```

JS

```
//This works, so it looks like focus should work an any element with tabindex set
$('#div').on('focus', function()
{
    console.log('Div focus event');
});

//This works, so it looks like the browser and Flash support the events
$('#swf').onblur = function()
{
    console.log('SWF onblur');
}

//This does not work
$('#swf').on('focus', function()
{
    console.log('SWF focus event');
});
```

Why does `onfocus` work, but `on('focus')` doesn't? Is jQuery doing something besides just forwarding the events?

Comment: Try $('#swf').focus(function(){});
or $(body).on('focus', '#swf', function(){});

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj Thanks, the second version works for me. If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this using just the jQuery object, not the id selector? e.g. `$(body).on('focus', $element, ...)`.

Comment: @SeanFujiwara No, not the way you have it there, as according to the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) docs, the (optional) second argument has to be a selector string instead of an already-selected object reference. This is so that dynamic event handling can work, well, dynamically. If you pass it the object, I think `.on()` will assume that is the optional third argument, `data`.

Comment: Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) the function accepts selector not the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(body).on('focus', '#swf', function(){});
```

Hope it helps